# Syntax Error of extracting day.month,year on customer transformer

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the written below custom transformer to extract day of week,month and year from columns . The I want the original columns to be dropped and also the day,month and year to have the original names of the columns as prefix

```
class DateExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
        def fit(self, X, y=None):
            return self

        def transform(self, X, y=None):
            columnA = pd.to_datetime(X.columnA)
            columnB = pd.to_datetime(X.columnB)

            cols = ['columnA ','columnB']

            return pd.DataFrame({
                "columnA_day":columnA.dt.dayofweek,
                "columnA_month":columnA.dt.month,
                "columnA_year":columnA.dt.year,
                "columnB_day":columnB.dt.dayofweek,
                "columnB_month":columnB.dt.month,
                "columnB_year":columnB.dt.year

            #drop columns A and B since we have already extracted day,month,year
                X.drop(cols, axis = 1)
            })
```

I get the below error

```
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: What's `X.drop(cols, axis = 1)` purpose here ? You cannot type something like this in `pd.DataFrame()`

Comment: @IronHandOdin I want to drop original columns A and B

Comment: your `transform()` function returns a dataframe which only the columns you define in it so you don't need to drop A and B columns. Delete `X.drop(cols, axis = 1)`.

Comment: You didn't write on which line you get the error, but please notice that you have unwanted spaces between "columnA" and ".dt" in the `return` statement.

Comment: @IronHandOdin I want the new values to be written to the original dataframe X and the original columns to be deleted

Comment: @FatmaJaffer then you need to do it before the `return` statement. `X.drop(cols, axis = 1)`  `return pd.DataFrame({"columnA_day":columnA .dt.dayofweek,  .... ,"columnB_year":columnB.dt.year})`

Comment: @IronHandOdin this does not add the new columns to the original dataframe

Comment: your function already returns new values. You can assign function to your df like this `X = transform(X)`. Do you understand the function concept ?